# distribute events evenly among persons

Tags: optimization, algorithms, covariance

I have a real live problem. Excuse me, if i'm not mathematically correct, I'm a developer, not a mathematician.

Following situation:
I have:

- a given list of events.
  eg. each Monday and Wednesday for the next 12 weeks (makes 24 event days).
- a given list of persons, with different participation percentages.
  eg. person1: 60%, person2: 20%, person3: 10%, person4: 10%

target:

- the events shall be distributed evenly among the persons, so that each event is assigned to one person
  Here's an example for 10 events and 4 persons:
  [image]

difficulties:

- a person may not be available for every calender event (eg he has vacation)

My math lesseon are long time ago, but i think you have to minimize the variance of the distance between the events of a person - for all persons? (i have no clue how to do that)

Would be glad to get some help here,
thanks.

Comment: The first wrong answer minimizes the variance, so I don't think that's the measure you want!  Perhaps minimize the sum of $u_{ij}/|i-j|^p$, for some power $p \ge 1$, where $u_{ij}$ is 1 if the same person is assigned to events $i$ and $j$, 0 otherwise.

Comment: You're right about the first wrong answer, if you stop with the 10 events. I was imagining an infinite repetition of the 10 events, while coming up with my proposal.